# Displaytag + Tomcat -> silent failure

Tags: java, tomcat7, tomcat6, displaytag

I'm trying to rehabilitate project which is approx 10 years old.

It is a java webapp which used to run well in Tomcat 6. There is a small cluster of modules which were variously built with Ant and Maven, using Java 5 and Java 6.

I've now got them all building correctly with Maven, using Java 6, deploying to Tomcat 7, trying to aim for the same version of dependencies - just to get it running, before attempting upgrades.

Some of the JSP pages use DisplayTag 1.2. If my Maven build includes the `displaytag` dependencies then the webapp doesn't run. There's no errors in the logs. It just reports a 404 for everywhere.  If I exclude `displaytag` from the Maven build, everything works fine, except the JSP pages needing DisplayTag.

If I try to run the webapp in Tomcat 6, I get exception to do with incompatibilities between commons-logging and slf4j.

If a webapp silently fails like this, with no errors or exceptions in the logs, what should I suspect or investigate?

---

### UPDATE

Based on Kayaman's answer, here is what I did:

1. Any place in any `pom.xml` which had a dependency on `commons-logging`, add the following:

   ```
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   ```
2. Where there is an explicit dependency on `commons-logging`, mark it as `provided`:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. When booting up the webapp now, this is what I saw in `catalina.out`:

   ```
   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webapp]]
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
           ... 10 more
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
           ... 24 more
   ```
4. Next I added to the top-level webapp `pom.xml` the SLF4J "re-router" for commons-logging:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.4</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
5. Also made sure that the SLF4J was wired up with Log4j, at the correct version (Log4J was the existing logging framework for this webapp, 10 years ago):

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.16</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
           <version>1.6.4</version>
       </dependency>
   ```
6. Now when booting the webapp, this allowed JSP errors and Exceptions to be seen in `catalina.out`, which I was able to debug successfully!

Comment: You don't need the exclusion if you give the provided scope, since the dependencies will see it as "oh there's already `commons-logging`, so I can leave it out", as sort of a global exclusion. Otherwise, nicely done! A textbook example of bridging to slf4j.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So including the displaytag dependency causes the jsp compilation to fail for all jsps, resulting effectively in the webapp not having any views, hence the 404s. At least a very plausible sequence of events.

According to [this](https://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/036d6nkwa7/jsp-compiler-output) any JSP compilation exceptions can be seen in tomcat's `localhost_log.xxx` file. However, the same thread goes on to complain that there's no info or not enough info, which probably means your logging config is borked.

For that you probably need to set up your [logging bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL).

Since you're using `slf4j`, but other components are using `commons-logging`, you're losing the log information from the other components. For that you include `commons-logging`, but as **provided**, so it won't be pulled in by other libraries.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And then you include the `jcl-over-slf4j` (which is what provides `commons-logging` as we promised above).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

This should allow components using commons-logging to bridge their logs to your slf4j (and to the actual implementation, logback or whatever).

Here's a [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) to Jasper's other config things, should they be necessary.

Comment: I want to give you a bounty for your answer. I need to wait 16 hours ...

Comment: @Stewart It's not very easy to remote debug blindly an unknown codebase and environment, but I figured if this doesn't help, you might encounter something along the way.

Comment: Oh! I need to wait another 24 hours to award a bounty!